# What is wrong with my nav links that the a:hover box doesn't include the padding? Only the content box changes color.

Tags: css, navigation, hover, navbar, nav

Im trying to make a navbar but I am having trouble with the a:hover.  only the content box changes color, but I want it to be the content box and the padded area around it.  What is happening?

I have tried everything, but for some reason only the content box changes, which looks awful.  I am trying to get a full box to change color.  I feel like an idiot, can someone look through this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```css
#container {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
 font-family: "avenir light", sans-serif;
}

#container{
 max-width: 980px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-links {
 max-width: 1090px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
 background: #831517;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-links a {
 color: #444444;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}


ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

.navbar {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 91px;
}

#number {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <title>Brushworks NW Inc.</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-links">
   <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
   <li id="number"><a href="#">(360)679-4444</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved the padding from `li` to `a`

See working code:

```css
#container {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

body {
 font-family: "avenir light", sans-serif;
}

#container{
 max-width: 980px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar-links {
 max-width: 1090px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-links a:hover {
 background: #831517;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-links a {
 color: #444444;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
}

.navbar ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 100%;
}


ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 91px;
}

#number {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 <title>Brushworks NW Inc.</title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-links">
   <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
   <li id="number"><a href="#">(360)679-4444</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: yes! that worked! what was I doing wrong? could you explain what it was doing what it was doing so I dont make this mistake again?

Comment: You want to change the background color on :hover of <a>. Since the padding was on <li> (the parent of a), the size of the <a> was the size of the text-content inside. By adding the padding on the <a>, the size of <a> is the content + padding.